# Beginner Python Keyboard GUI setup

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, keyboard

I am beginning GUI in Python 3.5, and I am trying to setup a simple qwerty keyboard. Based on the examples, I tried the following code

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RAISED, Button, Entry

self.window = Tk()

    #Keyboard
    labels = [['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'],
                 ['a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'],
                 ['z','x','c','v','b','n','m','<']]

    n = 10
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(n):
            n -= 1
            label = Label(self.window,
                              relief=RAISED,
                              text=labels[r][c])
            label.grid(row=r,column=c)
            continue
```

This gives me the first row, but it does not return anything else. I tried simply using 10 as the range, which created the first two rows of the keyboard, but it still did not continue onto the last row.

Comment: What is your intent with the `continue` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the line `n -= 1`. Every time a label is created, you make `n` one less- after the first whole row, `n==0`, and thus the range is 0>0, and ranges never include the high bound- `for c in range(0)` will just drop from the loop (as it has looped through all the nonexistent contents).

A better solution involves iterating through the lists instead of through the indexes- `for` loops take any iterable (list, dictionary, range, generator, set, &c.);

```
for lyst in labels: 
    # lyst is each list in labels
    for char in lyst:
        # char is the character in that list
        label = Label(... text=char) # everything else in the Label() looks good.
        label.grid(...) # You could use counters for this or use ennumerate()-ask if you need.
        # The continue here was entirely irrelevant.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want it to do? Let me know if you need me to explain it further but basically what I'm doing is first filling the columns in each row. So row remains 0 and then as I loop through the column (the inner list) I fill in each of the keys, then on to the next row and etc.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RAISED, Button, Entry


window = Tk()

#Keyboard
labels = [['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'],
             ['a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'],
             ['z','x','c','v','b','n','m','<']]

for r in labels:
    for c in r:
        label = Label(window, relief=RAISED, text=str(c))
        label.grid(row=labels.index(r), column=r.index(c))
window.mainloop()
```